# How can I make my computer fans less noisey

Tags: windows, noise, speedfan

I got this PC from overclockers:

- "Titan Envy M DC" Intel Core i7 4790K @ 4.4GHz Overclocked Nvidia GeForce Gaming PC
- MSI GeForce GTX 760 OC Gaming Edition 2048MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card
- Seagate Barracuda 2TB 7200RPM SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache - OEM (ST2000DM001) HDD
- Samsung 250GB SSD 840 EVO SATA 6Gb/s Basic - (MZ-7TE250BW)
- Kingston HyperX 8GB (2x4GB) PC3-19200C11 2400MHz Dual Channel Kit - Black/Red
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 64-Bit DVD - OEM (WN7-00614)

Also I upgraded the graphics card to a GeForce GTX980 so I can play even better games!

However - the fans (and I don't think its the GPU fans) seem really noisey :( 
There are two large fans on top of the PC (mini tower) and sometimes they just go beserk : (  ... but they are always quite noisy.

I tested the GPU using firestorm and MSI Afterburner... set the fans to 100% and then as low as they go. I could hear a secondary fan inside the box changing (I guess the GPU fans)...

So these fans on top of the box must be more related to the CPU?... I am not really sure.

Does anyone know how to control them? - is there some software to mess around with them? -they are a little bit dusty... but still I did clean them out when I changed the GPU (using a vacuum on low power).

Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you carefully use a compressor/other type of blower insted of a vacuum.

Yes there are software for adjusting your fans - Google is your friend - however, I've never had a satisfying experience due to compabality issues but you could give it a try I suppose; a better option would be to check your BIOS, most (especially newer motherboards) have some settings you can adjust for when they kick in and their maximum power.

I cannot give you specific advise since you dont mention Mobo-manufacturer, but BIOS is usually accessed pressing F12 or Delete on boot-up screen.

Hope this can help you a little. GL.